# Adjusting the argVector

Tags: c, linux

Part of my program is shown below:

```
char *argVector[] = {"./doTasks","0", "1", "3", NULL};
int numChild = 3;
int temp;
char tempstring[100];

for (int i = 0; i < numChild; i++)
{       
    temp = sprintf(tempstring, "%d", i);
    argVector[1] = tempstring;
    temp = sprintf(tempstring, "%d", 1 + i*3);
    argVector[2] = tempstring;
    printf("argVector is now: %s %s %s %s %s\n", argVector[0], argVector[1], argVector[2], argVector[3], argVector[4]);
}
```

My intended output is like below:

1st loop:

argVector[] = {"./doTasks", "0", "1", "3", NULL}

2nd loop:

argVector[] = {"./doTasks", "1", "4", "3", NULL}

3rd loop:

argVector[] = {"./doTasks", "2", "7", "3", NULL}

But on the actual console display I got:

1st loop:

argVector[] = {"./doTasks", "1", "1", "1", NULL}

2nd loop:

argVector[] = {"./doTasks", "4", "4", "4", NULL}

3rd loop:

argVector[] = {"./doTasks", "7", "7", "7", NULL}

My current program is about multi-processing in Linux (passing argVector to the child processes by execvp(); doTasks.c is another C program for the child processes to implement). Anyway before going too far, I am now already stuck in manipulating the argVector. Can somebody explain the weird output? Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: hint: `argVector[1] = tempstring` is assigning a pointer, not copying a string.

Comment: Also, your code does not do as you have written in the question.  The result is `argVector[] = {"./doTasks", "1", "1", "3", NULL}`, `argVector[] = {"./doTasks", "4", "4", "3", NULL}`, etc.

Comment: Very sorry for that since I have altered the code a bit before posting (I hardcoded argVector[3] as "3" for convenience). For argVector[3], the value is actually based on user input (user input an integer, then use sprintf() to do the string conversion and store it into argVector[3]......), which appears before the for loop for manipulating argVector[1] and argVector[2]. But I believe that the output mismatch is basically related to what you have mentioned ("assigning a pointer" vs "copying a string").

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be aware thnat in C there is no real string type unlike in other languages.

`char *argVector[]`  is not an array of strings but an array of *pointers*.

You want this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
  char *argVector[] = { "./doTasks","0", "1", "3", NULL };
  int numChild = 3;
  char string1[100];
  char string2[100];

  for (int i = 0; i < numChild; i++)
  {
    sprintf(string1, "%d", i);
    argVector[1] = string1;
    sprintf(string2, "%d", 1 + i * 3);
    argVector[2] = string2;
    printf("argVector is now: %s %s %s %s %s\n", argVector[0], argVector[1], argVector[2], argVector[3], argVector[4]);
  }
}
```

I also removed `int temp;` as it is useless here.

Another possibility is using a 2D array of `char`s rather than an array of pointers to `char`:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
  char argVector[5][20] = { "./doTasks","0", "1", "3", NULL };
  int numChild = 3;

  for (int i = 0; i < numChild; i++)
  {
    sprintf(argVector[1], "%d", i);
    sprintf(argVector[2], "%d", 1 + i * 3);
    printf("argVector is now: %s %s %s %s %s\n", argVector[0], argVector[1], argVector[2], argVector[3], argVector[4]);
  }
}
```

That way we don't even need `string1`, we can directly "print" into `argVector`.

Here `argVector` is more or less an array of 5 strings, each of which can contain at most 20 characters including the NUL terminator.

Comment: Great! I can see that you declared string2 in the program. But one thing I would like to clarify is that when the 2nd sprintf() is called, shouldn't the string1 be overwritten? (that is "i" replaced by "1+i*3" in string1, assuming I just declare string1 but not string1 and string2 both). Why do I need two temporary holders? Thanks so much!

Comment: @NicholasChin actually these 2 strings are not temporary, the both must exist simultaneously. If you had only `string1`, the problem would be the same.  `argVector[1]` and `argVector[2]` are not strings, they are _pointers_ to strings. You need to be familiar with the concept of _pointer_ if you want to program in C, except for the most basic things.

Comment: So if it is char argVector[5] = {.......}, then my previous stuff is totally correct. Just now it is char *argVector[] = {.......}, so I cannot directly do string copy here. Am I on the right track?

Comment: No not at all, `char argVector[5] = {.......}` declares an array of 5 `char`s. I'll enhance my answer. Just wait a bit.

Comment: Ah I see! I just mixed C and C++ together. So string[] in C++ is equivalent to char[][] in C. So char argVector[5] = {....} is an array of 5 chars, while char argVector[5][20] is an array of 5 strings (char[]) and each of them owns a length of 20. Am i right?

Comment: @NicholasChin _So string[] in C++ is equivalent to char[][] in C_, not quite. _So char argVector[5] = {....} is an array of 5 chars, while char argVector[5][20] is an array of 5 strings (char[]) and each of them owns a length of 20. Am i right?_ More or less. C++ std::string is a real string type, you can treat them exactly like integers, you cann assign them around as you like. Read the chapter dealing with strings in your C text book.